# Compiling CUPS 2.0 on 10.9: what archflags to use?

Tags: macos, install, cups

I installed CUPS 2.0.0 (cups.org) but evidently I needed to include specific architecture flags. Now several things are broken on my mac (e.g. Word won't boot). Error messages reveal that the problem is with libcups.2.dylib ("built with the wrong architecture").

Per advice I found for an earlier version of OSX, I tried re-configuring CUPS using:

configure  --with-archflags="-arch i386 -arch x86_64" --with-ldarchflags="-arch x86_64"

but that did not fix the problem. What is the correct archflag for building CUPS on 10.9?

Not sure if this is related, but now I can't get the Finder to show invisible files, which is preventing me from reverting to my pre-CUPS 2.0 configuration using Time Machine.

Answer (score 1):

I do not have 10.9 and CUPS 2.0, but I had a very similar experience with 10.8.5 and trying to get CUPS 1.7.2 up and running.  The default configure and make ONLY builds a 64-bit set of libraries.  I had success with using the same architecture flags for both the effective CFLAGS and LDFLAGS parameters:

./configure --with-archflags='-arch i386 -arch x86_64' --with-ldarchflags='-arch i386 -arch x86_64'
make clean
make

Before getting this straightened out, many programs (from Spotlight to Safari to Outlook) did not work with 64-bit only libcups*.dylib libraries.